# angular: json returns "Refused to execute script"

Tags: json, angularjs, wordpress, rest

When I try to pull information from my WordPress wp-json through a filter, I get the following response: Refused to execute script from '.... "because its MIME type (' application / json ') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

```
 var newsApi = 'http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/?filter[category_name]=news?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK';

// This should go in a service so we can reuse it
$http.jsonp(newsApi).
  success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

      $scope.news = data;

      console.log( data );
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.log( 'Post load error.' );
  });
```

Comment: `URL` must have `callback=JSON_CALLBACK` as query param, url should be something like `http://mywebsite.com/wp-json/?filter[category_name]=news?_jsonp=JSON_CALLBACK&callback=JSON_CALLBACK`

Comment: Also I am not sure but you have two `?` in URL. May be second have to be `&`?

Answer (score 0):

@Pankaj Parkar's answer worked for me. I had to add `?callback=JSON_CALLBACK` to the end of the url.

This is my API call in my Angular app.
`$http.jsonp('https://api.forecast.io/forecast/MY_API_KEY/' + lat + ',' + lng + '?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')`